# Mounting HDFS using Fuse-DFS?

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, filesystems, mount, fuse

I installed hadoop-2.6.4 in ubuntu 14.04 by compiling from source using the link https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=hadoop.git;a=blob;f=BUILDING.txt

My HDFS is working fine without any error. I need to mount HDFS into a remote machine.. Now iam trying to build Fuse-Dfs to mount HDFS to my local host. Could any one suggest proper steps for building Fuse-Dfs and mount HDFS??

I followed the link https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS for Building Fuse but when I execute

```
ant compile-c++-libhdfs -Dlibhdfs=1
```

it is giving error

> Buildfile: build.xml does not exist

I dont know from where I need to execute the above step..

My Aim is to mount HDFS to a remote host.. If any other better method is there please suggest it... because i am very new to Hadoop..